# How to loop a GUI using java?

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

[image]

[image]

im creating a game using java language. I am new to GUI. I want to be able to somehow loop a frame. For example, if the user pressed 2 players, the second frame should be able to show twice like "Player 1 name: " then after pressing enter "player 2 name: " should be the next one and then after pressing next another frame will show. I want to be able to update my GUI every time the enter button is clicked, and limit the update depending on how many players was chosen. The images shown below have different .java files

```
        while(i < game.getnPlayers()) {
            if (action.getActionCommand().equals("enter")) {

              // codes

            }
            i++;
        }
```

im trying to start with this code, but when i do. it doesnt get updated

Comment: This code is not enough to understand what you are doing, exactly. You should specify which GUI you're using (Swing? JavaFX? Web interface?) in the tags. Also, provide a [mcve]. In general, you don't loop the GUI, the GUI controls what happens. For further research: `CardLayout` which is part of Swing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have tagged the post with IntelliJ-idea, so I am assuming you are using the GUI designer. Graphical user interfaces use listeners to listen for certain input (OnMouseClick, ActionListener and so on), and then performs methods you assign to the listener. I would suggest reading some documents or watching some videos on the topic before moving on with your game.

[A source from oracle on writing Event listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)

[A video on making Java Swing GUIs using IntelliJ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vSyylPPEko)

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

On your GUI class you must have the button function. There you can create an function for when the button is pressed (in this case the "ENTER"), then you will see how many players were selected.

Comment: You need to understand that you don't loop the GUI, it doesn't need a 'while' to run. All you need is to call it once.